# Uploading multiple images with random file names

Tags: php

Right now, all the images upload fine with their file names, but I want to change the file names to random names (to avoid names with symbols) but when I try to do so, if I upload more than one image, they will all be the same image of the last selected file.

```
<input type='file' name='file[]'>
```

And the conditions:

```
 $allowed = array('jpg', 'JPG', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp', 'tiff', 'gif');
        $max_file_size = 2048*1000;
        $path = "images/images/"; // Upload directory
        $count = 0;
        if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
            if ($_FILES['file']['name'] != "") {
                foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $f => $name) {     
                    if ($_FILES['file']['error'][$f] == 4) {
                        continue;
                    }          
                    if ($_FILES['file']['error'][$f] == 0) {               
                        if ($_FILES['file']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                            $errors[] = "$name is too large!";
                            continue; 
                        }
                        else if( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $allowed) ){
                            $errors[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                            continue; 
                        }
                        else{ 
                            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name))
                            $images = array(
                                'images'    => $path.$name,
                                'ad_id'     => $_POST['id']
                                ); 
                                add_images($images);    
                            $count++; 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prepend the index to the image name. Try to change

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name))
```

to

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$f.$name))
```

(and the same principle for `'images'    => $path.$name,`)

Comment: That was actually exactly what I wanted! that .$f is what i was missing when I tried to make it work! Thank you!